# Named Pipes between C# and Python

Tags: c#, python, windows, named-pipes

I'm trying to create a two-way communication channel between two programs (one in Python and another in C#)

When I create a named pipe between two C# programs or two Python programs, everything is OK, but when I try to (for example) connect to the C# server from Python code, it does not work:

C# code:

```
NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream(
    "Demo", PipeDirection.InOut, 100, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
    PipeOptions.None, 4096, 4096)
```

If I use `win32pipe` in Python, code blocks on `ConnectNamedPipe` (it never returns)

```
p = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
    r'\\.\pipe\Demo',
    win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
    win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
    1, 65536, 65536,
    300,
    None)
win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(p)
```

If I use open function, it just establishes a connection, but nothing occurs:

```
open( '\\\\.\\pipe\\Demo', 'r+b' )
```

Now if I close the Python program, C# server receives just one data item from Python and a `System.IO.IOException` raises with "Pipe is broken" message

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: This question helped in writing [this blog post](http://jonathonreinhart.blogspot.com/2012/12/named-pipes-between-c-and-python.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I fixed the problem. I should seek to position 0 of buffer.

My Python code:

```
    win32file.WriteFile(CLIENT_PIPE,"%d\r\n"%i ,None)
    win32file.FlushFileBuffers(CLIENT_PIPE)
    win32file.SetFilePointer(CLIENT_PIPE,0,win32file.FILE_BEGIN)
    i,s = win32file.ReadFile(CLIENT_PIPE,10,None)
```

Answer (score 11):

According to [MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx), `ConnectNamedPipe` is the "server-side function for accepting a connnection".  That's why it never returns - it's waiting for a connection from a client.  Here's some sample code showing C# as the server and python as the client:

**C#:**

```
using (var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("Demo"))
{
    server.WaitForConnection();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write("\"hello\"");
        server.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
    }

    server.Disconnect();
}
```

**python:**

```
import win32file
fileHandle = win32file.CreateFile(
    "\\\\.\\pipe\\Demo", 
    win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE, 
    0, 
    None, 
    win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, 
    0, 
    None)
left, data = win32file.ReadFile(fileHandle, 4096)
print(data)  # "hello"
```

Comment: This works like a charm :) Thanks for saving a lot of my time, 8 years later :)

Comment: Indeed, a very simple and working example! I would just add one minor thing which took me some time. In this example, both processes needs to run with same elevated rights, otherwise you will get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are meant to use win32pipe.popen, not open.

Also try: pipe.flush(), pipe.read(), and time.sleep(0.01). Sometimes IPC takes a while to sync up.

I don't really know, that's my experience with the subprocess pipes. win32pipe might be different.

Comment: I used win32pipe.popen. Nothing changed
Have you managed to create a named pipe between Python and .NET ?
I don't know why win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(p) never returns

Comment: I also used win32file, but now the connection establishes but WriteFile does not work (Yes, I've also flushed the buffer)